# How to check a check box in PDF-form using Java PDFBOX api

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-form

How to check a check box in PDF-form using Java PDFBOX api

Initially I tried with the below piece of code but after the execution check box field is 
invisible in PDF , but it has been checked.. how to avoid such circumstances or they way i have implemented is wrong ?
can any one help me out

```
public void check() throws Exception 
    {
        PDDocument fdeb = null;

         fdeb = PDDocument.load( "C:\\Users\\34\\Desktop\\complaintform.pdf" );
         PDAcroForm form = fdeb.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
         PDField feld3 = form.getField( "check" );
         feld3.setValue("check");
         fdeb.save("C:\\Users\\34\\Desktop\\complaintform.pdf");
         fdeb.close();

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: here in above piece of code "check" is check box field name

Answer (score 11):

Finally got it work !!!! 
change made in setValue statment and replaced with  ((PDCheckbox) feld3).check();

```
public void check() throws Exception 
    {
        PDDocument fdeb = null;

        fdeb = PDDocument.load( "C:\\Users\\34\\Desktop\\complaintform.pdf" );

         PDAcroForm form = fdeb.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
         PDField feld3 = form.getField("loan");
         ((PDCheckbox) feld3).check();


         fdeb.save("C:\\Users\\34\\Desktop\\complaintform.pdf");
         fdeb.close();

    }
```

Comment: Strangely I had to use ```feld3.setValue(((PDCheckbox) feld3).getOnValue());```

Comment: If you are using scala - you will need `field.asInstanceOf[PDCheckBox].check()`